# Change Bitbucket login from username / password to login with Google

Tags: multi-factor-auth, bitbucket

I've got a Bitbucket account I setup using a username / password. At the moment Bitbucket doesn't allow you to have 2-step authentication on your account, so I want to change my Bitbucket login to be able to login with my Google account (which does have 2-step auth). Does any one know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

After logging in, head over to [Connected accounts](https://bitbucket.org/account/connected-accounts/) & click on Connect next to Google.

Alternatively, [at the Login page](https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/?next=/), if you login with Google, Bitbucket will offer to connect your existing account with the Google account if the email ids are the same.